# Multiple observableArray with Objects

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have two `observableArray`s with Objects:

```
self.firstHorizontalLineArr = ko.observableArray([{color: "red", val: 0},{color: "blue", val: 1}]);
self.secondHorizontalLineArr = ko.observableArray([{color: "blue", val: 0},{color: "red", val: 1}])
```

With these I create an `observableArray` like this:

```
self.testArr = ko.observableArray([{first: self.firstVerticalLineArr()},{second: self.secondVerticalLineArr()}]);
```

But if I now make this:

```html
<div class="test" data-bind="foreach: testArr">
   <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
```

Then `$data` is only `{object Object]`

How can I get the values of my `first` and `second` Array? So that I can get the colors, for example? I think I need a second foreach, but I don't know any further way to achieve this.

Comment: What is the purpose of `testArr`? What is `firstVerticalLineArr` (maybe you meant `firstHorizontalLineArr`)? Why pushing those 2 arrays to 2 objects with different property accessor (`first` and `second`)? Is your real intention to simply `foreach` on the combined values of both `firstHorizontalLineArr` and `secondHorizontalLineArr`?

Comment: Why don't you `merge` two arrays and set to one observableArray and then simply you can use your forach ,

Comment: Yes sorry i meant firstHorizontalLineArr. My code is normally much longer. I just edited it, that's why I wrote accidentally firstVertical. My purpose for this thing is a "Nonogramm". I really need the different lines, so I can't use only one Array.  The first Horizontal is for the upper line, the second for the next one and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's near impossible to answer the question as asked, but I see what your trouble is. Here's a way to get things clearer:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.firstHorizontalLineArr = ko.observableArray([{color: "red", val: 0},{color: "blue", val: 1}]);
  self.secondHorizontalLineArr = ko.observableArray([{color: "blue", val: 0},{color: "red", val: 1}])
  self.testArr = ko.observableArray([{first: self.firstHorizontalLineArr()},{second: self.secondHorizontalLineArr()}]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-bind="foreach: testArr">
  <strong>Original, but "toJSON" so you can see what it is:</strong>
  <div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
  <br>
  <strong>Demo 1, again "toJSON" to see what's going on:</strong>
  <div data-bind="foreach: !!$data.first ? $data.first : $data.second">
    <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></span><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <strong>Demo 2, rendered:</strong>
  <div data-bind="foreach: !!$data.first ? $data.first : $data.second">
    <span data-bind="style: { color: color }, text: val"></span><br>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

However, I'd recommend merging arrays slightly different, like this:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.firstHorizontalLineArr = ko.observableArray([{color: "red", val: 0}, {color: "blue", val: 1}]);
  self.secondHorizontalLineArr = ko.observableArray([{color: "blue", val: 0}, {color: "red", val: 1}])
  
  self.testArr = ko.computed(function() {
    return [{
      first: self.firstHorizontalLineArr(),
      second: self.secondHorizontalLineArr()
    }];
  });
  
  
  //[{first: self.firstHorizontalLineArr()},{second: self.secondHorizontalLineArr()}]
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="itemTmpl">
<li data-bind="style: { color: color }, text: val"></li>
</script>

<div class="test" data-bind="foreach: testArr">
  <strong>Demo 3, rendered:</strong><br>
  First:
  <ul data-bind="template: { foreach: first, name: 'itemTmpl' }"></ul>
  Second:
  <ul data-bind="template: { foreach: first, name: 'itemTmpl' }"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helped me a lot :) I did it with the computed version.